# Как сделать сброс в default-значение столбца таблицы MySql?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, default

Есть база данных из нескольких таблиц в которых, время от времени, изменяются столбцы у всех записей или выборочной. В свойствах столбцов каждой таблицы указано значение по умолчанию (default).

Во время работы с базой данных хочется уйти от постоянного запоминания и использования в коде этих значений, чтобы обнулять их и создать простой (универсальный) запрос для сброса столбца в значение, указанное для него по умолчанию.

Подскажите, такое возможно в MySQL? И если да, то как должен выглядеть такой запрос в MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, возможно. Достаточно в `update` запросе указать ключевое слово `default` в качестве значения.

```
mysql> create temporary table test (i int default 5);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into test values (10);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> update test set i = default;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test;
+------+
| i    |
+------+
|    5 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table test alter column i set default 10;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> update test set i = default;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test;
+------+
| i    |
+------+
|   10 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```